# UDP Packets Misfiring

Tags: c++, sockets, arduino, udp, coremidi

Trying to stage my question as generically as possible here. Perhaps I'm just thinking out loud.

My program should be sending one large packet, around 24bytes but instead it would seem that it's firing 6 packets of length: 2,2,4,4,4,8 respectively.

Transmitted from my Adafruit WICED Feather is:

[image: Arduino/Adafruit Serial Monitor]

So the packet getting sent by my PC is 24bytes in this case. The handshake should return a packet of roughly the same size. However here's what is getting picked up on the other end:

[image: rtpMidi Error Log]

As you can see, the incoming packets are of sizes 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, and then a buffer of 8+ bits.

My first thought is that there is something going on in the main write function, which is a template:

```
template<class UdpClass>
inline void AppleMidi_Class<UdpClass>::write(UdpClass& udp, AppleMIDI_InvitationAccepted& ia, IPAddress ip, uint16_t port)
{
   Serial.println("+++++ Writing Packet");
   udp.beginPacket(ip, port);

      udp.write(ia.signature, sizeof(ia.signature));
      udp.write(ia.command, sizeof(ia.command));

      // To appropriate endian conversion
      uint32_t _version = AppleMIDI_Util::toEndian(ia.version);
      uint32_t _initiatorToken = AppleMIDI_Util::toEndian(ia.initiatorToken);
      uint32_t _ssrc = AppleMIDI_Util::toEndian(ia.ssrc);

      // write then out
      udp.write((uint8_t*) ((void*) (&_version)), sizeof(_version));
      udp.write((uint8_t*) ((void*) (&_initiatorToken)), sizeof(_initiatorToken));
      udp.write((uint8_t*) ((void*) (&_ssrc)), sizeof(_ssrc));

      udp.write((uint8_t*) ia.name, strlen(ia.name) + 1);

   udp.endPacket();
   udp.flush();
}
```

This template is actually calling the following write function (6 times in fact):

```
size_t AdafruitUDP::write(const uint8_t* buffer, size_t size)
{
  if (_udp_handle == 0 || _sndIP == 0 || _sndPort == 0) {
    Serial.println("Handle, IP, port == 0 returning");
    return 0;
  }
  //Serial.printf("+++++ Handle: %s IP: %s Send Port: %s\n", _udp_handle, _sndIP, _sndPort);

  sdep_cmd_para_t para_arr[] =
  {
      { .len = 4   , .p_value = &_udp_handle },
      { .len = 4   , .p_value = &_sndIP      },
      { .len = 2   , .p_value = &_sndPort    },
      { .len = size, .p_value = buffer       }
  };
  uint8_t para_count = sizeof(para_arr)/sizeof(sdep_cmd_para_t);

  VERIFY_RETURN(sdep_n(SDEP_CMD_UDP_WRITE, para_count, para_arr, NULL, NULL), 0);
  return size;
}
```

This then calls:

```
bool AdafruitSDEP::sdep_n(uint16_t  cmd_id       ,
            uint8_t   para_count   , sdep_cmd_para_t const* para_arr,
            uint16_t* p_result_len , void* p_result)
{
  _errno = FEATHERLIB->sdep_execute_n(cmd_id, para_count, para_arr, p_result_len, p_result);
  handle_error(cmd_id);
  return (ERROR_NONE == _errno);
}
```

So, I think the next obvious question is: what happens during beginPacket and endPacket. Not much - I didn't see any callbacks either :

```
int AdafruitUDP::beginPacket(IPAddress ip, uint16_t port)
{
    _sndIP   = (uint32_t) ip;
    _sndPort = port;

    return 1;
}

/******************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Called after writing UDP data to the remote connection.
*/
/******************************************************************************/
int AdafruitUDP::endPacket()
{
  _sndIP   = 0;
  _sndPort = 0;

    return 1;
}
```

So my real question, before I get to changing someones wonderful library around, is this: does it look as though the header is getting written with each `appleMidi.write()` function? Is there a way to concatenate those 6 write calls from the appleMidi class?

I think I'm on the right track here but input is always much appreciated.

Sincerely,

-Daydreaming at work

Comment: Don't post text as images. Post text as text.

Comment: Sorry I'm at work I don't have the sample output just a few screen caps to work from :/

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that on your particular embedded system, a call to `udp.write()` corresponds to a transmitted packet, with the `beginPacket` / `endPacket` merely establishing and nullifying the context necessary to transmit one, rather than actually delineating boundaries.

The simplest solution may be to assemble your entire packet in a buffer, an then write that in a single call.

You might also want to take this to the Adafruit support forums.